# iOS addSubview of a new view controller does not work

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to do something like this -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];    
  ThingViewController *thingViewController = [self thingControllerForCard:self.card];
  thingViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
  UIView *view = [thingViewController view];
  [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

It just gives me a white screen with nothing in it. If I push the new view controller on the navigation stack it shows the controller properly. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: You shouldn't just add one VC's view to another view controller - you need to tell both VCs that they have a child/parent view controller.  The relevant method calls are described in [Implementing a Custom Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12) in Apple's View Controller Programming Guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the thingViewController frame on the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
`viewDidLoad` does not has the frames set correctly at this time:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    ThingViewController *thingViewController = [self thingControllerForCard:self.card];
    UIView *view = [thingViewController view];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    thingViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: This is on the right track but viewDidLayoutSubviews is really the correct place for a view controller to layout subviews. viewDidLayoutSubviews will get called, for example, if the view's frame changes. viewWillAppear only gets called when the view is added to a view hierarchy.

Comment: updated, thanks @rschmidt.
Funny i like to use viewDidLayoutSubviews for frame setting, dunno why i forgot about it.